# Date tool, have a photo in the post

Tags: xamarin.android

I am looking for how to use like this :

[image]

xamarin android.

Thanks advanced

Comment: you have to explain exactly what you want. Add more explanation to your question

Comment: how to do like this for select date by move up or down ?

Comment: I am looking for answer ? any idea guys